# How do I use the Moment API to shorten my existing code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

```
        var timeHH = scope.session.timeHH * 3600;
        var timeMM = scope.session.timeMM * 60;
        scope.session.time = (timeHH + timeMM) * 1000;
```

This is what I've already tried:

```
moment(scope.session.timeHH).format('HH');
```

Scope.session.timeHH is an text input field that pulls through a two digit number between 1 and 24 for the hours

Scope.session.timeMM is an text input field that pulls through a two digit number between 1 and 60 for the minutes.

I have done the maths above and it works fine but my company is also using moment but can't figure out what functions I need to use to do exactly the same maths in most likely less code.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Have you actually read the [momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/)?

Comment: Of course.. I have tried to do it with the format function but didn't get much luck. I'll update my question with that code actually.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Is the input a *duration* for how long until the session expires? Or is it a *time of day* that the session expires?  Also, if you're formatting only the hours component, then why even take in minutes? They would just be truncated. What kind of result are you actually looking for?

Comment: I'm also confused because it looks like you asked a similar question under a different user account [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37317401/634824).  It's almost the same thing.  Are there two of you???